# Handling addtional exceptions and throwing custom error message in Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring 2.5 .I want to do the following:
In the overriden  loadUserByUsername method of spring UserDetailsService I want to throw a custom exception and on that exception give a custom error message on the login page.
Could anyone suggest how can I handle this custom exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver and handle your exception in this class. Code is not full, but you can understand the idea from that part.

```
public class ExceptionResolver extends AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver {

@Override
protected ModelAndView doResolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
     ModelAndView mav;
     if(ex instanceof YourException){
         mav = loginController.showLoginPage();
         mav.addObject("errorMessage","Some error message text.");
         \\also you can change response code here or add some logic
     }
     else {
       \\some another page
     }
     return mav;
}
```

Also add this to applicationContext.xml(or another file with your spring context configuration):

```
<bean class="com.mycompany.ExceptionResolver" />
```